# Controlling dimensions of ::after

Tags: css

I've created a navigation using the CSS below to achieve equal distance between the nav elements. However, I've run into an issue where the ::after element creates empty space below the list area, the height of which I cannot seem to adjust.

See this image:

**Rendered List with wasted space**

[image]

```css
ul.formnav {
  padding: 0px 8%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: justify;
}
ul.formnav::after {
  background-color: red;
  content: 'This is wasted Space';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height
}
ul.formnav li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #999; /*Circle Formatting*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="formnav">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I can adjust the contents themselves, e.g. I can set `height:0px` and the red background will disappear or simply set `content:'';` but the space taken up by the `::after` element remains unchanged. Any idea how to fix this without dropping `display:inline-block` ? (can't use flexbox due to compatibility)

Comment: what is the purpose of `::after` in this case?

Comment: why not simply add margin to the li elements to add space in between them? https://jsfiddle.net/8nc8ft2x/

Comment: @cocoa - The `::after` is creating a second line so that the `text-align:justify` rule will equally distribute the elements on the first line. It's a bit of a spacing hack.

Comment: @j08691 ah, i gotcha.

Comment: if your elements have a fixed height, 30px, why don't you just set the height of your `ul`to 30px? No more undesired space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra white space that appears is due to the pseudo-element forming a line box in the new line, and the vertical spacing is the line leading divided above and below the baseline.

If you set `line-height: 0` on the parent container and then `vertical-align: top` on the pseudo-element, this will get shrink the white space to zero height.

```css
ul.formnav {
  padding: 0px 8%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 1px dotted blue; /* demo only */
  line-height: 0;
}
ul.formnav::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top; /* gets rid of space below the baseline */
}
ul.formnav li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #999; /*Circle Formatting*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="formnav">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the job. Brilliant! Thank you very much, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use flexbox:

```css
ul.formnav {
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
ul.formnav li {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #999;
  /*Circle Formatting*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="formnav">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```